# how to replace elements of a vector with elements from a vector which match throughout another item in R?

Tags: r, vector

how to replace elements of a vector with elements from a vector which match throughout another item in R?

I have:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c('x','w','e','c','t','z')

c <- c(2,3,5)
d <- c('xx','vf','z')

df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- data.frame(c,d)
```

I want df2 look like that:

```
a b
1 x
2 xx
3 vf
4 c
5 z
6 z
```

I have tried so far to merge/join them by "a" so i got:

```
a b b
1 x NA
2 w xx
3 e vf
4 c NA
5 t z
6 z NA
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `df1$b = as.character(df1$b); df1$b[which(match(df1$a, df2$c) > 0)] = as.character(df2$d[which(match(df2$c, df1$a) > 0)])`

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
full_join(df1, df2, by = c('a' = 'c')) %>% 
    transmute(a, b = ifelse(is.na(d), b, d)) -> result
```